# Why is the application title bar hidden under Unity's top title bar?

Tags: unity, 14.04, titlebar

In Ubuntu 14.04, The title bar of my application goes under the main title bar of Unity.

In the image below, the selected window is of Download Manager, but its title bar is hidden under unity's top title bar.

[image: This is how it actually looks]

I find this issue occurring with web apps and standalone apps.

Ideally it should look like this:

[image: This is how it should look]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a subtle bug to me which seem to occur randomly in my case. To work around it, resizing the window from its bottom edge fixes the issue.

Place your cursor at the bottom of the application window in order to change it to re-size mode; and then just drag your mouse to the bottom edge of the screen. That would make the title bar visible once again.

[image: This is how the cursor should look like for you to be able to resize the window]

<sub>The screenshot is when using Ubuntu GNOME, but this is how the cursor would also look in case of Unity.</sub>

Comment: Yes, this is a temporary solution. But can this issue be fixed permanently ?

Comment: @arpitnot4u I don't have a permanent solution at hand. You might consider [filing a bug on Launchpad](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).